# Can I pause a dc2.large redshift cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've read on the Redshift [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-cluster-operations.html#rs-mgmt-pause-resume-cluster) that you cannot pause/resume certain kinds of Redshift clusters (excerpt extract from the documentation):

> You can't pause the following types of clusters:
>
> - EC2-Classic clusters.
> - Clusters that are not active, for example, a cluster that is currently modifying.
> - Hardware security module (HSM) clusters.
> - Clusters that have automated snapshots turned off.

I want to estimate costs for a redshift cluster comprised of dc2.large nodes, but it isn't clear if this type of cluster accepts pause/resume. If it does accept, how much does storage costs while it is paused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `dc2.large` cluster can be paused.

From [Cloud Data Warehouse – Amazon Redshift Pricing– Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/pricing/):

> During the time that a cluster is **paused** you pay only for **backup storage**.

And later:

> **Backup storage** is the storage associated with the **snapshots** taken for your data warehouse.

And finally:

> With **dense compute (DC)** and dense storage (DS) clusters, storage is included on the cluster and is not billed separately, but **backups are stored externally in Amazon S3**. Backup storage beyond the provisioned storage size on DC and DS clusters is billed as backup storage at **standard S3 rates**.

So, it would *appear* that you will still be charged for **storage** when a DC2 cluster is paused. This is charged at standard Amazon S3 prices, which would be `$0.023 per GB per month` (varies by region).

If you have a lot of "downtime" on your cluster, you could consider **Amazon Redshift Serverless**, which automatically scales based on usage.